# clearInterval doesn't stop the interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

i have an if statement that checks if the c variable reaches 100 and then calls clearInterval, but the code keeps running. if I move the c++ in the timer function, then the c stays 0.

I have a codepen here
https://codepen.io/geo555/pen/WYJdQd

```
var c=0;
var elem=document.getElementById("counter");
elem.innerHTML="1";

window.onload = timer;

function timer(){

         var myInterval = setInterval(count,50)
         if (c==100) {
             clearInterval(myInterval)
         }
}

function count(){
    c++;
    elem.innerHTML=c;
    console.log(c)
}
```

Comment: `myInterval` is local, for one, and also, `timer` only runs once, and `c` surely hasn't reached 100 that first time `timer` runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*myInterval* is local to the function *time*. Make that *global*. Clear the interval inside *count()*:

```js
var c=0;
var myInterval
var elem=document.getElementById("counter");
elem.innerHTML="1";

window.onload = timer;

function timer(){
   myInterval = setInterval(count,50)     
}

function count(){
  c++;
  elem.innerHTML=c;
  if (c==50) {
   clearInterval(myInterval)
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="counter"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem because you're checking `c` variable *outside* the interval.

```js
var c=0;
  var elem=document.getElementById("counter");
  elem.innerHTML="1";

  window.onload = timer;
  
  var myInterval;

  function timer(){
      myInterval = setInterval(count,50)           
  }

  function count(){
      c++;
      elem.innerHTML=c;
      console.log(c)
      
      if (c==100) {
          clearInterval(myInterval)
      }
  }
```

```html
hello
<div id="counter"></div>
```